XSD import without attributes
I'm wondering whether the following XSD line is valid and what does it mean should it be valid?
<xsd:import/>

Full code can be found here

So why not just attempt to validate the schema?

didn't got you, you know the answer or not?

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#composition-schemaImport whichs says

Note: Since both the namespace and schemaLocation [attribute] are
optional, a bare <import/> information item is allowed. This simply
allows unqualified reference to foreign components with no target
namespace without giving any hints as to where to find them.


It 'allows' something... hence it should make some sense. If you could translate that note into English... Can you explain practical usage of it?

The practical usage of having no schemaLocation attribute is explained: "The ·actual value· of the schemaLocation, if present, gives a hint as to where a serialization of a ·schema document· with declarations and definitions for that namespace (or none) may be found. When no schemaLocation [attribute] is present, the schema author is leaving the identification of that schema to the instance, application or user, via the mechanisms described below in Layer 3: Schema Document Access and Web-interoperability (§4.3).". And no target namespace namespace means elements/attributes in no namespace.

thanks for your answers. You citate the case when schemaLocation missed and application should provide the way to load the schema. That imply schema is known (id or URI of the schema, that is what namespace is for) isn't it? But why it is allowed for both to be optional? What practical use case could it cover?

The namespace is not the location of the schema, though both tend to be URIs. If you don't provide a schemaLocation you pretend you work in an environment or with an application that works with some set of schemas for certain namespaces (which might include the null namespace). So the practical use case is to be in an environment / work with an application where a schema for no namespace exists and you want to import that. Perhaps start with the schema primer https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/ if the detailed spec appears to be too technical.

I'm not saying that namespace is a location of the schema, I was trying to say that namespace uniquely identify schema elements hence it could be treated as some kind of schema id. It makes pretty much sense to have import with namespace which application should know where to lookup for the actual data. I cannot grasp why W3C left possibility to omit both attributes namespace and schemaLocation and how this could be practically used

at first this looks like a bug in the schema. And I would be pretty confident in this standpoint unless I found this in well known public API which is not new (has many versions) of the pretty big company (claimed 20 000) which work with xml as a mainstream
